# Can a Conformed dimension also be a slowly changing dimension?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I would like take customer table as an example where it can be a conformed dimension in most cases. I wonder if it can also be considered as slowly changing dimension. If I take a record where a customer changes his phone number(just for the purpose of example considering phone number) and if I am tracking the history in two columns(Current phone number & previous phone number) then it is a SCD right?. Please advise

Comment: These are two separate concepts. There is no reason a SCD can not also be conformed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a conformed dimension can also be a slowly changing dimension.
If the data is tracked in the way you describe it is a slowly changing dimension, regardless of whether that dimension is used in multiple business processes/facts (i.e. is conformed).